# No standard wrapper implementation for MultiValuedMap

Tags: java, apache-commons-collection

Am I missing something, or is there really no default implementation of Apache's new [`MultiValuedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.2/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html) that could be used to simply wrap provided `Map<K, ? extends Collection<V>>`?

In other words, I am looking for a direct replacement of the now deprecated [`MapUtils.multiValueMap` factory method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html#multiValueMap-java.util.Map-org.apache.commons.collections4.Factory-): none of existing implementations like `HashSetValuedHashMap` meet my needs as I need to use `IdentifyHashMap` as backend map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to implement necessary helper method myself:

```
public static <K, V, C extends Collection<V>> MultiValuedMap<K, V> multiValueMap(Map<K, C> map,
        final Factory<C> collectionFactory) {
    return new AbstractMultiValuedMap<K, V>(map) {
        @Override
        protected Collection<V> createCollection() {
            return collectionFactory.create();
        }
    };
}
```

Though, with how trivial the implementation is, I cannot believe it is not there in `commons-collections` already.